# How to stop intellij-idea from marking profiles/dev as resource root?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

My project structure is like this:

```
src
  main
    java
    profiles
       dev
       prod
    resources
```

the `resources` folder is my resource root, but every time I restart IDEA, the `profiles/dev` folder is ALSO marked as resource root. And when I debug the application, property files inside `profile/dev` is used instead of files inside the `resources` folder.

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause for this may be that your project is a Maven (or Gradle) project and the Maven (or Gradle) project configuration *instructs* IntelliJ to treat the `profiles` folder as a resources folder.

In a Maven pom.xml this might look like:

```
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      /path/to/profiles
    <resource>
  </resource>
</build>
```

If that's the root cause then your could change your pom.xml to prevent IntelliJ from treating the `profiles` folder as a resource.

Alternatively, you could explicitly mark this folder as excluded in the Project Structure dialog (though if the root cause is Maven or Gradle build configuration then this would be overriden the next time you reimport the project into IntelliJ) ...

- Open `File > Project Structure`
- Select `Modules` then select whichever module you want to configure
- Select the `profiles` folder
- Click on the `Excluded` button

From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html):

> **Excluded roots**
>
> Files in excluded folders are ignored by code completion, navigation and inspection. That is why, when you exclude a folder that you don't need at the moment, you can increase the IDE performance.
>
> Normally, compilation output folders are marked as excluded.
>
> Apart from excluding the entire folders, you can also exclude specific files.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  the root cause is Maven build configuration. And, marking the `profiles` folder as `Excluded` doesn't work, because when I restart idea it will still be marked as resource folder.